# Sensitivity of a variable

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Assume i have a graph with 2 variables y vs x. And lets assume we have an exp function y=exp(-x). Now how does one define the sensitivity of one variable to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the best measure of sensitivity of a function is its elasticity, defined as

$ x\cdot \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} $

but meaningful only for positive functions of positive numbers. It gives the change of the function in percentages as the argument $x$ changes $1\%$ near $x$.
So it is independent of the used scale. Much used in economics.
For details see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_of_a_function

EDIT: it is $f'(x)/f(x)$ !!